# iOS and Android build, but Android keep getting an error

Tags: android, ios, cordova

This is the scenario i'm currently using. I'm running out of options on how to make my Android environment work. This is my first App.

I'm using OSX to build for iOS and Android, using *Cordova CLI* (no ionic, no nothing, plain CLI). The command to create the platforms ends with no errors displayed. It appears to create the iOS and Android platforms correctly. In addition, i had this previously working properly. My PATH is set. It is telling me that i had my platform-tools and tools for Android SDK

```
sudo cordova platform add ios
sudo cordova platform add android
```

After i run the command to build the app, the iOS works as expected but android does not. i get the following error

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/kratos/Documents/projects/testApp/testApp-mobile/platforms/android/src/com/testApp/myApp'

At this point, any idea can be useful since i ran out of them

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Please answer the following questions in your post, then respond in the comments, so I know you have updated your post. 
Is this your first App? What is your target platform? What is your Build platform? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ?

Comment: i think i cover your questions

Comment: @ian-cornado, your English is weak. I have cleaned up your post. I do not know how to fix your issue. This blog may help [iPhoneDevlog](https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/), and here is a [list of blogs](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/documentation/phonegap/bookmarks/topBloggers.html). This is from the first blog [Setting Up Your Development Environment for Cordova/PhoneGap Android projects](https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/setting-up-your-developmemt-environment-for-cordovaphonegap-android-projects/)

Comment: Don't run cordova by using sudo, this is the best way to go in trouble. Just add the platform with: cordova platform add ...